# How to get the docker image name with tag using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I use the following method to get a Docker image name with tag:

```
os.path.basename('mydocker.hub.internal.io:8000/OS/alpine:3.17'.split(':', 1)[1])

os.path.basename('registry.intuit.com:3060/library_excluded/nginx:latest'.split(':', 1)[1])
```

That gives me the expected outputs - `'alpine:3.17'` and `'nginx:latest'`.

But I would like to know if there is more right and elegant way to do it?

Python version - 3.7

Comment: I would use -1 index to get tag. I believe the paths may also have `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [docker-py](https://pypi.org/project/docker-py/) package.

I don't know about "elegant", but the package makes it convenient, because it is a wrapper around Docker API, which handles parsing of image names and tags, amongst other functionalities. I recommend reading through the package's full documentation at: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.

For example, if I have the following images on my env:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY        TAG                     IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
my-custom-image   my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4   d64578606786   8 days ago      130MB
elasticsearch     8.7.0                   fd60cca4e217   5 months ago    1.33GB
nginx             latest                  2b7d6430f78d   12 months ago   142MB
dgraph/dgraph     v21.12.0                4012c5ca9405   21 months ago   294MB
```

The [`client.images`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/images.html#) methods can list out the available images:

```
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> 
>>> for image in client.images.list():
...   print(image)
... 
<Image: 'my-custom-image:my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4'>
<Image: 'elasticsearch:8.7.0'>
<Image: 'nginx:latest'>
<Image: 'dgraph/dgraph:v21.12.0'>
```

Each [`Image`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/images.html#image-objects) object has various attributes such as getting the image tag:

```
>>> for image in client.images.list():
...   print(image.tags)
... 
['my-custom-image:my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4']
['elasticsearch:8.7.0']
['nginx:latest']
['dgraph/dgraph:v21.12.0']
```

If you need a specific image, you can use either [`client.images.get(name=...)`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.get) passing in the full image `name:tag` or [`client.images.list(name=...)`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.list) passing in a pattern for the image:

```
>>> nginx_image = client.images.get(name="nginx")
>>> nginx_image.tags
['nginx:latest']
>>> nginx_image.tags[0]
'nginx:latest'

>>> my_image = client.images.get(name="my-custom-image:my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4")
>>> my_image.tags
['my-custom-image:my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4']
>>> my_image.tags[0]
'my-custom-image:my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4'
```

```
>>> my_images = client.images.list(name="my-custom-image")
>>> my_images
[<Image: 'my-custom-image:my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4'>]
>>> my_images[0]
<Image: 'my-custom-image:my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4'>
>>> my_images[0].tags[0]
'my-custom-image:my_custom_tag.1.2.3-4'

>>> nginx_images = client.images.list(name="nginx")
>>> nginx_images
[<Image: 'nginx:latest'>]
>>> nginx_images[0].tags
['nginx:latest']
>>> nginx_images[0].tags[0]
'nginx:latest'
```

With this solution, you don't need "manually" parse with code like `.split(':', 1)[1]`.

Note that:

- The images have to exist on your local env for the above methods to work. Basically, it returns the same info as what you get with `docker` CLI command.
- The [`.tags` attribute on `Image`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/images.html#docker.models.images.Image.tags) objects always return a list, because the *same* image can have *multiple* tags. If you expect only 1 image, you can simply just get the `[0]`-th item of the list.

Comment: Well explained with examples.